# python logging,open notepad can't understand the content

Tags: python, logging

I use the following code to record the log,there are English and Japanese and Chinese in it."aaa" is English."くれ対応"is Japanese."我啊"is Chinese.

```
import logging
import datetime
import os

logger = logging.getLogger()
now_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')
log_file = now_date+".log"
if not os.path.exists("log"):
    os.makedirs("log")
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s line:%(lineno)s %(message)s')
file_handler = logging.FileHandler("log"+os.sep+log_file)
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter) 
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.error('aaaくれ対応我啊'.encode('utf-8'))
```

When I open the notepad,the content is this:

```
2018-03-20 10:28:46,451 ERROR line:2161 b'aaa\xe3\x81\x8f\xe3\x82\x8c\xe5\xaf\xbe\xe5\xbf\x9c\xe6\x88\x91\xe5\x95\x8a'
```

I can't understand b'aaa\xe3\x81\x8f\xe3\x82\x8c\xe5\xaf\xbe\xe5\xbf\x9c\xe6\x88\x91\xe5\x95\x8a'.
How can I turn it into the original Chinese and Japanese when I open the notepad?

Comment: You need to use an editor that understands UTF-8 Encoding. Use Notepad ++ or something

Comment: I use notepad++ open this file,and I choose "utf-8" to encoding,but there is no difference.

Comment: @rdp Which might be true but unrelated to the problem.

Comment: Try to remove the `encode()` call. It creates a bytes type which is always represeted as an escape sequence.

Comment: When I remove encode('utf-8'),a mistake has happened.UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp932' codec can't encode character '\u554a' in position 48: illegal multibyte sequence
Call stack:
  File "test1.py", line 2161, in <module>
    logger.error('aaaくれ対応我啊')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to configure the encoding in the filehandler instead of encoding yourself

```
file_handler = logging.FileHandler("log"+os.sep+log_file,'w', 'utf-8')
```

remove encoding in the last line

```
logger.error('aaaくれ対応我啊')
```